# XCode 8 Create Framework with Pods

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Anyone tried to achieved on how to create a framework that has a pods dependent?

I already create a workspace for the framework with pods and it will build successfully. But when I add the framework to another project it will have an error No such module(Pod framework)

Comment: can u share how u did it? and did u fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`No Such Module` happened for me a lot of time when I added Pods to my project, and that's because the Pods was not created with the current Swift syntax and it was automatically converted to it, but that should not stop the project from building, so, after multiple Clean and Build the project ran with me.